Why do I get a statement timeout when dropping a column from a large table?
I have a very large table (over 1 TB in size) in a PostgreSQL database, and it has a text column, which is also large and uses TOAST. When I try do drop the column, it times out after 20 minutes. There is no index on that column.
I am trying to drop it using the code below:
ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN b;

I am getting an error stating the statement is canceled due to timeout.

SQL Error [57014]: ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout

How can I speed up dropping ofthe column?
I tried to increase statement_timeout, but it still times out even after 30 minutes.
EDIT: I see that there are about 100 locks in a normal time on the table , most of these are AccessShareLock and a few RowExclusiveLock
EDIT: table attributes:



total_size
data_size.
index_size
toast_size
tablespace




1363 GB
224 GB
103 GB
1036 GB
[NULL]



EDIT: I tried to get the lock exclusively in the lowest activity time but it keeps failing to get the lock and giving the lock_not_available. The code is below:
DO $$
BEGIN
    -- Set local session parameters
SET LOCAL statement_timeout = '10m'; 

     
    -- Attempt to acquire the lock on the table, fail fast if not possible
    BEGIN
        LOCK TABLE a IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE NOWAIT ;
    EXCEPTION WHEN lock_not_available THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Could not acquire lock on table: Table is in use';
    END;

    -- Attempt to drop the column
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN b;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE WARNING 'Error during operation: %', SQLERRM;
        RAISE;  -- Re-raise the exception after logging
    END;
END;
$$; 

When I ran
 SELECT l.pid, locktype, mode, granted, query, age(now(), query_start) AS query_duration
    FROM pg_locks l
    JOIN pg_stat_activity a ON l.pid = a.pid
    WHERE relation = 'a'::regclass;

I still saw a few AccessShareLock and RowExclusiveLock 's
If I remove the NOWAIT clause I m getting a general

[22171]:ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout error

, which means the lock was acquired right?

There is no constraint on the column, there is an application running 24/7 reading/writing to the table that's the only concurrent transaction

It's slow because something has the table desciption locked.
If there is an autovacuum, dump, or other slow process locking the table description you should wait for that to complete first.
You are perhaps the victim of priority inversion
NOWAIT is not going to help you. the table is too busy. You are going to have to wait, (and thus temporarily stall new  transactions until the old ones complete) to fee up the table for modification.
The actual modification will take is milliseconds to complete once the lock is obtained.
You could try the following:
begin; lock table a ; ALTER TABLE a DROP COLUMN b; commit;

if you have slow queries on table A you're going to have accept an outage or to shut that application down temporarily,

you are going to haver to wait, (and thus temporarily stall the other transactions) if you want to get this table modified,

So its expected to take more than 30 mins to drop the col?

closer to 30 milliseconds, I can't say how long it will take to get the lock

getting the lock takes more than a few seconds as far as i see , but my question is about the drop operation:  do we expect it to  take more than 30 mins, some people says its meta operation

it's just an update to a few internal tables, it takes a fraction of a second

It takes more than 30 mins in my case, any idea why?

I can't think of a reason

Try this (see fiddle here):
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 0;  -- sets value for local transaction only

CREATE TABLE t_copy AS SELECT x, y FROM target  -- dropping TEXT field z
WHERE 1 = 1  -- filter for unwanted records (if any)
ORDER BY x;

ALTER TABLE t_copy ADD PRIMARY KEY(x);  -- put your required indexes here
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON target (y);

DROP TABLE target;

ALTER TABLE t_copy RENAME TO target;  -- should be fast

COMMIT;

That might get around the problem if it's concurrent transactions. You need to alter the statement_timeout because no matter how you do it, copying 1TB of data is going to take time (+ the indexing overhead)- but it will be non-blocking! Test it first to see if there are any issues.

that will break triggers and foreign keys.

@Jasen  The OP said there was no constraint on the table and didn't mention triggers!

Consider what might need to happen when you issue the drop column statement. In every row with a value in this column, the pointer to the value in the toast table should be cleared and every linked data page in the toast table should be marked for recovery. In a big table, that could be a lot of work.
You could perhaps consider deleting the data in batches, before dropping an empty column.

That also is extremely slow, it took 10 hrs to nullify only 10% of the rows, not sure if there is a way to speed it up
